# if statement executing when condition is false

Tags: c++

I'm tinkering with a projecteuler problem and I encountered the following really odd behaviour. And I can't for the life of me figure out whats going on.

[image: Screenshot]

As the screenshot shows. The condition evaluates to false, and the if-statment executed as if it was true.

I feel like I'm going crazy here.

Updated code: http://ideone.com/L7KMu

Edit: The actual values for next.x and next.y just prior to the condition are
0.324583, 9.97891

The are unchanged after the if statement.

Comment: Your image is really not clear - at least on my monitor

Comment: It is quite big, try view image...

Comment: Does it might be that the statement modifies the variable? Maybe you should create a watch for the variable itself.

Comment: It is possible you're invoking undefined behaviour somewhere.  If so, all bets are off.  Alternatively, perhaps your debugger is out-of-sync with your code-base.  Please construct a minimal test-case, and post the code here.

Comment: How do you know the condition evaluates to false? You don't appear to be printing out the value you are checking.

Comment: Can you stick some print/cout statements in around this code too? Might help differentiate between an issue with the compiled code versus the debugger view.

Comment: @Loggie Take a look at the watches windows from the debugger at the left

Comment: @Loggie the debugger tells me so.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe I do apologise, I never seen the watch window.

Comment: I used to get this thing with different compiler (embarcadero) if I had not rebuilt a project correctly. Debugger output would not correctly run on the lines it should do. I am not sure if the same happens with your compiler but maybe try rebuilding everything

Comment: ideone produces the same results as I do.

Comment: Strangly enough, your program seems to run fine on CodePad, http://codepad.org/OY6sPYTn

Comment: abs(next.x) is being printed as 0.

Comment: @Loggie, just saw I'm using abs(int ), now it is even stranger that codepad runs it fine.

Comment: Echoing comments above, use print statements, that would have caught the issue. IDEs are nice, but printf is still a pretty sharp tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having compiled the code, it appears that the abs you are calling is not std::abs, overloaded for floating point, but integer abs. Try this amendment to the code:

```
// get the root not relating to this point
nextX = (abs(solved.first - next.x) < EPSILON) ? solved.second : solved.first;
nextY = k * nextX + m;
prev = next;
next = point(nextX, nextY);

cout << abs(next.x) << ", " << std::abs(next.x) << endl;
if ( std::abs(next.x) < 0.01){
    cout << "Here1" << endl;
    if ( next.y > 0){
        cout << "Here2" << endl;
        foundExit = true;
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the cout line is printing different values for abs and std::abs.

Comment: Yep.  Just the conclusion I was coming to.

Comment: My pleasure. And thanks for posting the full code sample. Makes it much easier to help.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe So the debugger must have been doing different resolution of abs from the compiler. Which is interesting, and possibly a bug.

Comment: @AlexWilson Yes, that is my take on it too.

Answer (score 2):

abs(next.x) is being evaluated as 0 because it is between 0 and 1 This rounding will be dependant on the compiler being used.